# JSR223 Sampler does not show Groovy language option in apache JMETER

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Current Jmeter version -5.2.1

I even tried by setting up the classpath as below in the jmeter.properties file -

user.classpath=/usr/local/Cellar/groovy/3.0.4/libexec/lib

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

1. [Current JMeter version is 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) and according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should be always using the latest stable JMeter version, it can be obtained from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page
2. JMeter 5.2.1 comes with [Groovy 2.4.16](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/gradle.properties#L77), it might be better to stick to that version just in case
3. You need to restart JMeter in order to pick up any properties or [classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) changes
4. If you installed JMeter using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) it might be the case the Groovy library was deleted by someone by accident, you can get it back like `brew reinstall jmeter`.
5. And last by not the least you can always drop the library(ies) you need to add to JMeter to `/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/5.2.1/libexec/lib/` folder